# Is $\frac{1}{\phi(b)} \sum_{1 \leq x \leq b, (x, b) = 1} e^{-\pi i a x / b}$ continuous in $a$ and $b$?

Tags: number-theory

Let 
\[
f(a, b) = \frac{1}{\phi(b)} \sum_{1 \leq x \leq b, (x, b) = 1} e^{-\pi i a x / b},
\]

with $a < b$, $(a, b) = 1$.

Then is $f(a, b)$ continuous in $a/b \in \mathbb{Q}$ ?

This question just aroze during an excursion into some problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For $a=2A$ and $gcd(A,b)=1$ then $\phi(b) f(a,b) =\sum_{b\le x, gcd(b,x)=1} e^{-2i\pi Ax/b}=\sum_{d | b} \mu(d)\sum_{x\le b, d | x} e^{-2i\pi Axd/b} =\mu(b)$ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramanujan%27s_sum#Formulas_for_cq(n)

Comment: I didn't realize that the sum is actually the famous Ramanujan sum (and it was a long time ago when I read about it). I see some interesting formulas for it in the link given by you, but do they say anything about its continuity/discontinuity, rigorously speaking?

Comment: If $0 < |A_n/b_n - A/b| \to 0, \gcd(b_n,A_n)=1$ then $b_n \to \infty$ so $\phi(b_n) \to \infty$ and $\mu(b_n)/\phi(b_n) \to 0 $ which is not always $=\mu(b)/\phi(b)$